# Cross-entropy via softmax: Mathematical derivation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science-model

I am trying to understand the derivation of cross entropy loss in the context of softmax. However, some steps are still not clear to me. Hence, I would appreciate if someone could please explain.

y = one hot encoding (representing true label) = selector

$y ̂= $value predicted by NN and the softmax.

Through the NN:
$X\xrightarrow{\smash{NN, θ}} Z \xrightarrow{\smash{Soft-max}} \hat{y}$

To derive the loss function, we start out from the likelihood function that a given set of parameters θ of the model can result in prediction of the correct class of each input sample. The maximization of this likelihood can be written as:     $$ arg⁡ max _θ L(θ|y ̂,Z) $$

The likelihood $ L(θ|y ̂,z) $ an be rewritten as the joint probability of generating t and z given the parameters θ, which can be written as a conditional distribution:
$$ L(θ│\hat{y} ,Z)=P(\hat{y} , Z│θ)=P(y ̂│Z,θ)P(Z│θ) $$
Since we are not interested in the probability of z we can reduce this (assumption 1):

$$ L(θ│y ̂,Z)∝P(y ̂│Z,θ) $$

Which can be written as $P(y ̂|z) $ for fixed θ (assumption 2).
Since each yc is dependent on the full z and only 1 class can be activated in the t we can write
$$ P(y ̂│Z)= ∏_{(c=1)}^C(P(y ̂_c |Z))^{y_c} =∏_{(c=1)}^C((SoftMax(Z))^{y_c }=∏_{(c=1)}^C(y ̂_c )^{y_c} $$

Assumptions 1 and 2 are not clear to me. Some explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Arguably this is a better fit for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. $P(Z|\theta)$ is independent of $\hat{y}$ so it can be left out as merely a multiplicative factor as we are interested in $\hat{y}$.
2. $\theta$ is a parameter and for each model is indeed fixed, it is not a variable

Comment: $ \theta $ is the parameter that we are optimizing. So, it does not make sense to me to claim that it's fixed for each model. Similarly, since P(Z|θ) is also a function of $theta $, I can not understand why one can claim that to be a multiplicative term

Comment: Actually we are optimising to have maximum correct predictions (given the model parameters $\theta$) that is $maxP(\hat{y}|Z,\theta)$. So we are interested in $\hat{y}$ which given a model is parametrised by $\theta$. But $\theta$ **is not** a random variable nor part of data. It is important to understand this.